# Why did S I Tilak shoot through a bottle?

Tags: plot-explanation, krack

In the 2021 Telugu movie *[Krack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krack_(film))*, police officer S I Tilak shot an innocent boy but due to a conspiracy, S I Veera Krishna got suspended from his post instead. This is how Tilak shot the innocent boy:

[image]

Why did he shoot him through a bottle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen the movie but if the intention is to frame another officer then this would seem to be a "soda bottle silencer".

The effectiveness of this in real life is debatable but they are treated in the movies as being on a par with actual suppressors.

[image]#